# Duda sobre git y crear ramas

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

tengo un proyecto de git donde tengo la rama develop y master.
He creado una rama nueva con el comando "git checkout -b feature/feature_Pruebas"

Entonces entro en esta rama y edito un fichero que es "carController.php".
Entre medio quiero hacer otra feature (rama) para hacer otra cosa y subir los cambios.

Para ello lo que hago es irme a la rama de develop con el comando "git checkout develop" pero al hacer este comando git me dice

```
dani@pc:~/Projects/test$ git checkout develop
M       carController.php
Switched to branch 'develop'
Su rama está actualizada con «origin/develop».
```

Y desde alli lanzo otra feature con el comando  "git checkout -b feature/feature_Pruebas2"

Esto lo que hace es arrastrarme este fichero... para no hacer esto y poder tratar las features en separado que deberia hacer un stash de esos ficheros?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si en la rama `feature/feature_Pruebas` modificaste `carController.php` debieras commitearlo antes de cambiar de rama.

```
git commit carController.php -m "modifica carController por motivos X"
git checkout develop
git checkout -b feature/feature_Pruebas2
```

Y ojo, acá no estoy considerando que puede que quieras pushear los cambios al remoto antes de cambiar de rama.

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a trabajar en dos "features" al mismo tiempo, clona el repo "remoto" en dos repos git locales distintos (en dos dirs distintos del disco duro local), uno para cada feature.

Eso es lo mas practico, y lo menos propenso a errores. Sobre todo si algun fichero es modificado en las dos features.

Y luego cuando ya hayas terminado las dos, las tengas probadas por separado, haces merge de las dos a develop y pruebas todo otra vez en develop...